# Android HttpPost Crash, Can't Debug?

Tags: android

Device is a Xoom Tablet. For some reason I can't do a HttpPost, when I try I can't trap the error. I tried a bunch of basic examples and they all crashed out the same way (see stack trace). I will attach my manifest in case I missed a permission. I know it's happening in the `client.execute(post);` statement. The error is not trapped and all I get is what you see in the stack trace below. I have tried a bunch of different ways but I can't for the life of me tell what the real error is. The post data does not seem to matter, same thing happens with a simple HttpGet request. What on earth am I missing?

Block in question

```
try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://share1.iqperspective.com/test");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avar", "test data"));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                client.execute(post);

            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                Log.v(TAG, "catch1");
            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "catch2");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "catch3");
            }
```

Mainifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.quisenberry.iqperspective"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/img_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="IQPerspective" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

The Stack

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NetworkOnMainThreadException))  
DefaultRequestDirector.execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 530    
DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 555 
DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) line: 487    
DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 465 
IQPerspective$13.onClick(View) line: 294    
Button(View).performClick() line: 3100  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 11644 
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 126 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3997    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 491  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 841  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 599 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the name of the exception (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`) tells you what's going on. You need to execute your networking code on a non-UI thread. See the article [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) for more info.

This is something new to Honeycomb. See the [docs for the exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) for more info.

Comment: thank you sir, I completely over looked the obvious error. i had not seen threading in any of the examples I found online and just misread it as a generic exception on the main thread. whats left of my hair thanks you.